# Google Play Compatibility Issue

Tags: android, google-play

I have released an app on Google Play that has a minimum API level of 17 (Android 4.2).
I have a test phone running Android 4.4.2.
The app is currently released only as beta. When I attempt to download it, it says its not compatible.

Has anyone got any ideas what could cause this?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.delaneybiometrics.delaneymobile"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 9
    versionName "0.9"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.3'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

}

Here is the Manifest...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>-->

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".PunchActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OnSiteActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TourActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please add the manifest and build.gradle to the question

Comment: Does your device have a camera? If yes, does it feature autofocus? Including the `android.hardware.camera.autofocus` feature *implicitly* declares the `android.hardware.camera` feature which most likely overrides your `android:required="false"` of the `android.hardware.camera` feature.

Answer (score 1):

To fix, remove the `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />` tag from your manifest.  But dont worry, [as the docs say below](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.AutoFocusCallback.html), your app will still work properly

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.AutoFocusCallback.html

> Devices that do not support auto-focus will receive a "fake" callback
>   to this interface. If your application needs auto-focus and should not
>   be installed on devices without auto-focus, you must declare that your
>   app uses the android.hardware.camera.autofocus feature, in the
>    manifest element.

Comment: I've removed the <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" /> tag from the manifest. It is still not compatible. The update has gone through because its just updated on one of my other devices.

Comment: It is a Vodafone Smart 4 running Android 4.4.2. I have several other test devices and this is the only one that claims to be incompatible.